# need to redirect mobile users to mobile pages

Tags: php, redirect, mobile

I have mobile website and desktop website. the corresponding URLs on both the platforms are different. I need 2 things here; 
1. the mobile visitor need to be redirected to the mobile website. 
2. the mobile visitor should be redirected to the corresponding mobile page the visitor is viewing.

The desktop version is developed in PHP. Mobile website is developed using a tool thus creating a general mobile application website that is accessible through browser on all the mobile devices.

The code I presently use in the htaccess file for mobile redirects is as below.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Check for mime types commonly accepted by mobile devices
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "text\/vnd\.wap\.wml|application\/vnd\.wap\.xhtml\+xml" [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^ http://m.site.com/
```

This is not redirecting the mobile visitors to mobile site. So, please help me in getting the redirects to work.

Should I add separate htaccess files for desktop website and mobile website?

Thanks
Somesh.

Comment: What is exactly your question? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Secelite, I have used the above mentioned code in my htaccess; m.site.com being our mobile website

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is something like this:

http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

htaccess redirect is filled under apache.

I would also suggest you to check for mobile useragents on multiple levels (like apache, PHP/ASP/whatever and JavaScript/jQuery)